# Subdomain always redirects to main domain. Why?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, virtualhost

when I request `site1.example.com` I get redirected to `example.com`. In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` I have setup a `site1.example.de` file with following content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example/site1"
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example/site1>
          Allow from all
          AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After

```
sudo a2ensite site1.example.com
```

and reloading apache it still redirects me to main domain. Any ideas why?

I use `apache2/2.2.14 (Ubuntu 10.4)`. My server is acting as nameserver.

Comment: Does the address displayed in your browser change, or does it stay the same and just send you the content from the main site?

Comment: the url stays the same but displays the content from the main page

Comment: Looks like your new vhost file isn't taking effect - I wonder if your main vhost isn't using the same host/port combination (`*:80`)?  Can you provide the output from `apache2ctl -S`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those wacky configs from `/var/www/vhosts/` (looks like they're from Plesk?) are using the full IP as their vhost address declaration, so the `*:80` listener won't ever get any requests to that IP.  Assuming that you only have that one IP on your server, this isn't desired.

Change the `<VirtualHost>` line in your newly created host, to have it be used for requests that hit the Plesk-created name-based vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 83.169.46.168:80>
    ServerName site1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/example/site1"
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/example/site1>
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Apache error logs for entries trying to get to the sub-domain. Most of the time I've had this issue Apache could not find the directory on the server (or file permission issues).